# How to import a class from a directory to the children of another directory

Tags: django, import, django-rest-framework, directory

I'm currently trying to import a class from a directory to a child of a different directory. I try not to use sys.path and use relative imports, however it keeps giving the error about attempted relative import with no know parent package. So I do not know if it's feasible to import a class from a directory which has higher level in project tree to a grandchild of a different directory? In this case, I want to import a class `ModelTest` in `model.py` in app folder to output.py. All the sub-directories have `__init__.py`, except the myproject directory.

Thank you

Here is my project tree, app and mainModel is at the same level:

```
myproject
  /mainModel
    /api
       /script
          /output.py

  /app
    /model.py
```

Django REST framework

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do `from ....app.model import ModelTest` from the `myproject/mainModel/api/scripts/output.py`, then this will not work:

- `from .sibling_module import something` tries to import `something` from "sibling module `sibling_module` of current package" (`myproject/mainModel/api/scripts/sibling_module.py:something`)
- `from ..sibling_of_current_package import foo`: goes to "parent package of current package of current module", then to module "sibling_of_current_package"
- ...
- The critical part here is "something of/from **PACKAGE**", and you don't have `myproject/__init__.py`, so `app` and `mainModel` are top-level packages.

This means that you cannot "import anything beyond them" using relative imports. So in your case you'll need to use absolute imports (`from app.model import ModelTest`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to use t but it didn't work. It showed error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'. So do you have any other suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: how are you running the script? When you are running a script that is not "installed" (e.g. `python3 ./myproject/mainModel/api/scripts/output.py`) then only system-packages and packages from script's directory are available (and packages in script directory are considered to be top-level). So you should either "install" your package or change PYTHONPATH (`cd myproject ; PYTHONPATH=. ./mainModel/api/scripts/output.py`)

Comment: I just ran the script as normal in VS Code with gitbash: I set the path cd ./myproject/mainModel/api/scripts/output.py and then run it with python output.py. Yes, so it probably is the problem. Do you know how to install the package "app" in order to run the output.py?